# Ruby Rack App - Couchbase DNS/Hostname lookup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, rack, couchbase

I'm using couchbase as session storage in my rack application (couchbase gem v1.3.9).

When I test the rack app with some more request (for example 50 parallel threads in jmeter)
or just reload the app many times, I allways get this error:

**Rack app error: Couchbase::Error::UnknownHost: bootstrap error, DNS/Hostname lookup failed (error=0x15)>**

My questions: 
Anyone else here has such error, when using couchbase with ruby and how  can I solve this?
What about performance of couchbase as sessionstore in a ruby rack application?

Additional informations:

My **config.ru**

```
session_options = PlainRackApplication::Config.session_options
use ActionDispatch::Session::CouchbaseStore, session_options

run RackApp.new
```

and my couchbase options

```
module PlainRackApplication
  class Config
    @session_options = {
      path: '/',
      namespace:'sessions_',
      key: 'foo_session',
      expire_after: 30.days,
      couchbase: {bucket: "foo",
                  username: 'foo',
                  password: 'bar',
                  default_format: :json}
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In what environment did you encounter this error?
If this happens on your localhost, verify that
`127.0.0.1  localhost`
is included in your /etc/hosts. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The **(error=0x15)** error message suggest that one of the host names in the bootstrap list is incorrect.

The client randomise the boot strap list, so that explains why you are only seeing it when you make more requests or if you you reload the application a number of times.

Further more creating and destroy couchbase client objects can slow down your application. If you can you should try to use a long live persistent connection that is used by all of your requests.

A number of users do use couchbase as session store mainly because of its high performance.

Comment: Additionally, the library may sometimes erroneously report a 'hostname' error when the issue in fact being unable to create a new socket, possibly because your file descriptors are maxed or because the TCP connection table is maxed at the system level

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answers!
As it happens also on localhost, I dont think wrong host name in bootstrap list is the reason.

The TCP connection maxed at system level, could be the reason, but it's maybe interesting how this could be tested.